# Trigger after Update based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 columns in a table and this are.

[image]

when a new item is inserted it will look like this

[image]

I have a seperate table that look like this (based on the above image) it will appear like this

[image]

It looks like more of a logs. Now I have a code for that.

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_on_tbl1
AFTER INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO table2 (Person1,Item,tag) VALUES (New.Person1,New.Item,'Inserted');
```

now here is my question lets there is a modification happen something like this

[image]

and the responsilble for updating is on the Person1 Column (AAA) how can I insert that in my logs table? actually i have a code here for that and here it is

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_basedon_tbl1
AFTER UPDATE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
IF IFNULL(NEW.Person2,"") = "" THEN
INSERT INTO table2 (Person1,Item,tag) VALUES (New.Person1,New.Item,'Modified');
END IF;
```

The problem here now is if the person who updates comes from `Person2` still it saves the logs how can I fix that? I mean I want that all logs will be saved if changes are made from `Person1` column only.

Comment: Not clear about what you are asking. If the person updates the column `Person2`, you don't want an entry in the second table?

Comment: yes sir all changes will be saved if it is inserted or changes is from `Person1` col

Comment: Not sure what you mean changes from Person 1. It's a column. Do you mean changes to that column?

Comment: yes sir on that column

Comment: What would your update statements be for updates by person1 and/or person2?

Comment: just the typicall update lets say like this `UPDATE table SET Person1 = Qty = '100' Person1= 'AAA' WHERE Item = 'Item1'` same goes with person2

Comment: The first thing mysql does in a trigger is write all table column values to all OLD and NEW columns it then overwrites all the NEW columns with values passed by the update statement. ie NEW columns always have a value even if none are passed from the update. That means it's not possible for you to detect who made the change with the structure you have after initial null values for person1 or person2 have been updated.

Comment: @P.Salmon maybe i will just use select based on item code (we assume this is unique) so based on that select if person2 col is null or not

Comment: Slight amendment - The first thing mysql does in an UPDATE trigger...